# get value of selected dropdown

Tags: jquery

I need to get the value of selected dropdown and not the text. eg: IN for India in dropdown.

```
<select id="country">
<option val="IN">India</option>
<option val="CN">China</option>
<option val="AU">Australia</option></select>

<div id ="get"></div>
```

​
Script:

```
    $("#get").text($("#country").val());​
```

Please refer http://jsfiddle.net/yxMSK/3/

I am making a silly mistake somewhere but unable to find it. Plz help.

Comment: correct your html and put the jquery stuff inside combo change event...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTML is wrong:

```
<option value="AU">Australia</option></select>
```

You need to replace val="" with value=""

Comment: @user1338585 awesome. Please accept and upvote (accept when possible)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#country").change(function(){
 $("#get").text(($(this).val()));
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yxMSK/18/

Comment: It gives me country name. But I require the value for the country name like IN against India or whatever value stored in option.

Answer (score 0):

here you go http://jsfiddle.net/cGt5N/

you need to hook up `.change event` so that every time you change the text changes.

**code** to get the selected value in your text field

```
 $("#country").change(function(){
    $("#get").text($("#country option:selected").text());
});
​
​
```

Answer (score 0):

On your HTML it should be `value` instead of `val`:

```
<select id="country">
  <option value="IN">India</option>
  <option value="CN">China</option>
  <option value="AU">Australia</option>
</select>
```